# React.useCallback() is still re-rendering child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

1) I am passing a handler method **onPaginationChange** to child component(B) as prop from a parent component(A)

2) I use useState() hooks so every time when I call setFieldName() the parent component re-renders and so the child component even when the handler is not invoked.

3) I am trying to use useCallback hook to avoid re-rendering child component because of parent component's state change. But, still I see the child component is re-rendering plenty of times based on number of state changes on the parent component.

here's my handler function passed as an arg to useCallback. Handler function receives 2 props **currentPageNo**, **pageSize** and I am using currentPage as a dependency.

```
const onPaginationChange = useCallback((currentPageNo, pageSize) => {
    const startRow = (currentPageNo - 1) * pageSize;
    const newData = apiResponse.slice(startRow, startRow + pageSize);

    setCurrentPage(currentPageNo);
    setGridData(newData);
}, [currentPage]);
```

Let me know if you find the root-cause of the issue.

Comment: If currentPage changes, useCallback will return the updated reference to the function. If currentPage changes a lot, components that depend on the callback will rerender.

Comment: Component B rendered on every changes in its props or states, if there is no more props or state change so `onPaginationChange` changes. `onPaginationChange` change on `currentPage` changes. Also I think `onPaginationChange` should not depend on `currentPage`. Why you do that?

Comment: @BonjeFir Actually, I want the currentPage to change every time onPaginationChange handler gets invoked, that's why I call setCurrentPage(currentPageNo) inside the handler.

This onPaginationChange handler is passed down to a child component and I see the child is getting rendered every time a state changes at the parent level. Instead I want the child to render only when handler is invoked.

Now, how do I stop the child rendering when only Parent's state changes and no prop to child is changed?